# Modify webpack.config.js of create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, configuration, webpack, babeljs

I want to modify the existing webpack.config.js file of Dan Abramov's create-react-app - I want to add an extra loader 'react-html-attrs' so that I can use class tag as is without changing it to camel-case className

So here is what I did :
1. I went to official github doc of this babel plugin - https://github.com/insin/babel-plugin-react-html-attrs and it said that if you're using babel-6 install npm package:
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-react-html-attrs

and then in one of my component js i returned a jsx containing class instead of classname - but I'm still getting this error message.

How to add custom babel loaders in webpack config of create react app??

Also which one to edit  - there are 4 such files in the directory??

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it isn't possible to add new babel plugins unless you [convert to a custom setup](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#converting-to-a-custom-setup).

By running `npm run eject`, you will be able to modify the Babel and webpack configs to your liking, with all the (dis)advantages it contains.

Comment: If I do npm run eject - will it only affect the CRA installation of that folder/project?
Or will it affect the globally installed npm package - such that I will not be able to use create-react-app command ever again?

Comment: Fortunately, only for that single project. :-)

Comment: wow great - this opens up all kind of interesting possibility

Answer (score 1):

Enter your project dir and run

```
npm run eject
```

This will extract all of the configuration files for you to edit, including webpack.config.js, to a folder called "config". Enter `config/webpack.config.js`, find the "return" statement, and inside there is a "resolve" configuration option. Add the following to that object:

```
symlinks: false
```